# Reference to CTE from another file

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I use CTEs (common table expressions) in SQL developer to make my queries more structured, and also with the intent to create "bricks" which I can reuse in queries.

For the second purpose it would be good to keep those CTEs in a separate file, so I don't need to browse for the latest version.

Is it possible to refer to CTE in another file in Oracle's SQL developer?

I know I could create queries / views in the database and use them, but unfortunately I don't have access to that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be code templates in SQL Developer itself. So you could code up your most frequent CTE's and invoke them with the keyboard.

I talk about those [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/11/sql-editor-code-templates-a-must-know-trick/)

But basically you code them up in the preferences, and give them a name.

Then type the name, and hit ctrl+space to invoke the template.

You can also set these up as Auto-Replace.

[image]

For what it's worth - you CAN reference code from other files using the @ and @@ commands. However, it will take the contents of that file and execute as a complete, standalone SQL statement or series of statements, so I don't think you can use this to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's definitely a comfortable way to add them. However it's not substantially better then keeping them in a separate file, and copying in the query once I need, as when I improve them (in the query where I use) I still need to go back to templates and update there too

Comment: I would agree, although if i used this feature - i would no longer update them in files...to avoid what you just mentioned. I'd of course back them up.

Comment: My CTEs are long (up to 100 lines) I'm not so professional to edit them in the templates:(, need to work in the query first to see it actually works.